# Getting only last message for each user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing PM system for my site. I created subpage for each conversation by two users. I am having hard time programming the front page, where all conversations are printed. I cant get only one and last meassage for each user.

Here is my function:

```
    public function fetch_data($id_uporabnika) {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM zs WHERE za = ? ORDER BY datum");
    $query->bindValue(1, $id_uporabnika);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

And here is my code for printing conversations:

```
            <?php
        } else { 
            $zs = new Zs;
            $id_uporabnika = $trenutni['id'];
            $zsji = $zs->fetch_data($id_uporabnika);
        ?>
        <h2>Zasebna sporočila</h2>
        <ul class="vsi-zsji">
            <?php foreach ($zsji as $sporocilo): ?>
                <?php $od = $oseba->fetch_data($sporocilo['od']) ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>zs/poglej/<?php echo $sporocilo['od']; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>inc/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $od['slika_potem'] ?>&w=60&h=60" alt="">
                        <p><b><?php echo $od['uporabnisko_ime'] ?></b></p>
                        <p><?php echo $sporocilo['vsebina'] ?></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
```

I get 10 PMs from one user, 3 for another. I want to display just the latest one.

Comment: User array_pop and get the latest element of array!

Comment: Maybe you should, at first, rename all of your variables to english. It's a pain to get what you want to do on a glance.

Comment: you probably want a `GROUP BY` in your query, grouping on user, plus the usual hack "top n per group" stuff.

Comment: A hack is not required! But a GROUP BY could be useful, especially where performance is an issue.

Comment: What is $id_uporabnika? Is it the ID of a single user?

Comment: Also, what is $sporocilo['od']?

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `LIMIT` clause in your SQL query and order by `DESC` to get the latest message:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM zs WHERE za = ? ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Tried that, I get only one conversation overall, not one for each user.

Answer (score -1):

something like this should help

SELECT id,datum, max(pm) FROM zs WHERE za = ? group by id,datum

Comment: Please explain why and provide more context regarding this code change